# React Contenteditable - how can I assign an onClick to a <span> in react-contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

Is there anyway I can use something like this:

```
<span onClick={(e) => console.log(e)}>Testing</span>
```

Inside [react-contenteditable](https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable) to handle the click on `Testing` keyword?

When I use the html prop, it would only take an html string, something like `<span onclick="something()"></span>` I suppose, but is there a way to do it in `react` instead?

And if I use `<span onclick="something()">` where should I define this function `something()`? I suppose at this point I won't have access to the functions defined in react, right? So how should I do this?

Comment: I think you will need to do something with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Comment: As a prop for the `ContentEditable`?

Comment: You mean you want to treat text you are writing in contenteditable as React? Or some element of the contenteditable itself?

Comment: I want to add a click listener to part of the text in a `ContentEditable`, for example if the ContentEditable html is `My name is <span>Ali</span>` how can I add `onClick` to this span?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onClick` is a React property so `react-contenteditable` wouldn't know what to do with it - since `html` expects plain html

A hacky way to achieve what you want - or pretty close to it - is:

1. Create an `onClickContentEditable` function and is it as `onClick` for `ContentEditable`
2. Add an `innerRef` to `ContentEditable`
3. in `onClickContentEditable`, then the clicked element is `ContentEditable` do nothing - since we want to interact only with the children of `ContentEditable`
4. Based on DOM attributes of the clicked element (`tagName`, `className` ...etc) fun with it! :)
   In `onClickContentEditable` you can check the DOM attributes of the clicked element and take action accordingly.
   You could create a class to mark the element you want to click.

You can test this implementation [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-rich-text-editor-in-react-t5jle?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) - the sandbox is forked from the complex `react-contenteditable` example. I logged the interactions in the console.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign any React DOM events on children of the `react-contenteditable` component, because internally it converts all the children to plain HTML string via [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) React prop:

https://github.com/lovasoa/react-contenteditable/blob/master/src/react-contenteditable.tsx#L53

All React bindings will be lost once the node is rendered